# Guardar y exportar un txt en una unidad de red

Tags: c#, asp.net

Logre que me guardara en una carpeta especifica, pero al mismo tiempo se esta quedando en la carpeta descarga y no se como quitarle para que solo se me guarde en la ruta que le estoy pasando

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( "select * from prueba ") 
using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
    {
        sda.Fill(dt);

        string txt = string.Empty;

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                //Add the Data rows.

                if (column.ColumnName.Equals("cantidadF"))
                {
                    txt += row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",000", "").Replace(".000", "");

                }
                else if (column.ColumnName.Equals("cantidade"))
                {
                    txt += row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",000", "").Replace(".000", "");
                }
                else if (column.ColumnName.Equals("Peso"))
                {
                    txt += row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",000000", "").Replace(".000000", "");
                }
                else if (column.ColumnName.Equals("Volumen"))
                {
                    txt += row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(".", "").Replace(",", "").Remove(4, 3);
                    //.Remove(4,3)
                }
                else
                {
                    txt += row[column.ColumnName].ToString();
                }
            }
            //Add new line.
            txt += "\r";
        }
        //Download the Text file.
        Response.Clear();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "'" + TxtExportFactura.Text + ".txt" + "'" );
                    string filename = TxtExportFactura.Text + ".txt";
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    Response.ContentType = "application/text";
                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"\\xxserver\mult\mult\CROSS\" + filename, txt);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();

//...
```

Comment: Muy bien, pero...y tu pregunta? El código que muestras...que problema tiene? Te lanza alguna excepción? No te lo exporta? Edita tu pregunta y añade mucho mas información o es posible que sea puesta en espera.

Comment: ¿como se define la variable `txy`?

Comment: Ya puse todo el codigo que tengo, cuando lo voy a guardar deseo que sea en la carpeta `J:\FACTURAS\CROSS`

Comment: Dudo que por razones de seguridad puedas definir en tu código una ruta por defecto para la descarga. Me temo que no es posible, cada usuario puede definir su ruta de descarga por defecto

Comment: Entonces como puedo hacer para ponerle una ruta por defecto

Comment: Segun se desprende de mi comentario...no puedes por programa, deberás configurarlo en cada navegador

Comment: Ya logre que me guardara en la ruta, pero tambien se me esta guardando en la carpeta de descargas y no se como decirle que no me guarde en esa carpeta.

Comment: A mi me pasaba lo mismo, pero ese método Response, se encuentra ligado con los Exploradores. Lo cual no te permitirá quitar la carpeta Descargas. (Dicho de otro modo, es una propiedad nativa de WEB. donde configures la salida ahí se estarán alojando los archivos). No te pelees con eso si ya lograste la salida a la carpeta que querías. Saludos.